# Model pop up is working but not in Pop up fashion in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

Im using Blazor and wanted to achieve Pop up functionality for notification or information.
I have used this [post](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/creating-a-reusable-javascript-free-blazor-modal) to do that and everything working fine, the only thing is pop up window is showing in page without click and window is not popping up as i expected. 
I have also tried with the project which is available on [Github](https://github.com/chrissainty/BlazorModal) and it is working fine, the only thing is if im tried to implement it Pop up window is appearing on every page as i have added model on Mainlayout.razor component without clicking on button.

[ScreenShot of Pop up window which is not popping Up, still in left corner of every page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYHNI.png)

Please help me, if im missing something.

RAZOR COMPONENT CODE

```
@page "/"
@inject SessionState  state
@inject IModalService Modal
<div id="Login_div" align="center">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ShowModal">Login</button>
</div>

@code {

private void ShowModal()
{
    var parameters = new ModalParameters();
    parameters.Add("FormId", 11);

    Modal.OnClose += ModalClosed;
    Modal.Show<YesNoPrompt>("Sign Up Form", parameters);
}

void ModalClosed(ModalResult modalResult)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Modal has closed");

    if (modalResult.Cancelled)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Modal was Cancelled");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(modalResult.Data.ToString());
    }

    Modal.OnClose -= ModalClosed;
}
```

Please note `@inject IModalService Modal` im using which i mentioned in my above para with post or github as it is impossible to show full code here.

Comment: I miss to provide your code, actually, Nobody can help without your code.

Comment: i have provided github link as well as post,im using same code in application by taking reference of Blazor model, any way i will update razor page as well, thanks.

Comment: You should post the code as text, it's much more readable, most users don't click on links. use github markdown, it works

Comment: @aguafrommars, updated the code of Razor component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One small detail I could find is that you are subscribe and unsubscribe to events without implementing the IDisposable interface. This could lead to memory leak and some hard to find bugs.

Like navigating away from the page without calling the `ModalClosed` method.
A small sample

```
@using System
@implements IDisposable

...

@code {
    public void Dispose()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for the official doc.